# Redirect to another page with ASP

Tags: redirect, asp-classic

I am not an asp developer, I work with PHP. But my problem required a little bit of asp.

Google has stored in his database links from an old website. So that links are showed after a google search, and the people is going to a particular file that was done on the old website (with asp).

I have my new website and need to redirect from that old website to the new one. So I have made a small research and found that to redirect in asp I need to:

```
  <%
  Response.Redirect ("my website link");
  %>
```

But the file only print text and dont redirect to the my new link.

What I am missing? I need only redirect to a particular page.

EDIT

The name of the old file is members.asp

I dont have a way to avoid google to point to that file, but of course that files doesnt exist on my server. Now I have created it and try to redirect but I only get the code printed in plain text.

You can check the live result here:

http://kln.cuisinecourier.com.hk/members.asp?rest_id=K013&lang=eng&sort=&m=login

ANSWER

ok I just realized that I can run javascript easily :S the simplest way. sorry for bothre

Comment: If you know it's an ASP question then why tag it as PHP!? Dropped tag.

Comment: you probably dont run asn asp.net file and asp.net not run - and is not only asp, is asp.net, the asp is reference to the old asp classic script.

Comment: Please specify is you talk about asp classic, what your files name, and what did you see render exactly.

Comment: i edited it, and put the link to see the live result

Comment: You use here asp-classic - and apparently not run at all, and the line is not for asp but for asp.net

Answer (score 3):

The Classic ASP code you have written, shown below, is correct:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "https://www.cuisinecourier.com.hk/en/hk/orderingGuide";
%>
```

but... Classic ASP is part of the Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS) web server. The web server you are using to serve at the following URL:

http://kln.cuisinecourier.com.hk/members.asp?rest_id=K013&lang=eng&sort=&m=login

...is not running IIS, but is running Apache (Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.5.11 according to the headers).  That web server does not process Classic ASP, hence it simply serves the unprocessed file contents.

Comment: kenny any idea what I can do to redirect anyway?

Comment: You've worked out how to do it with js.  If you want to do it with server side code then I'm sure there's a way to add a mapping to .htaccess which tells Apache to treat files with the .asp extension as php files

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect this way:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "http://www.yourwebsite.com"
%>
```

Source: [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_redirect.asp)

Comment: this is the correct command - after you make asp page runs on your site !

Answer (score -1):

Response.Redirect("Account/login.aspx"); will redirect to new page so check you give proper path to redirect or not.

Comment: its clear say that is not redirect and show only text